# is there a way to make random numbers in a list that i can decide how many numbers that should be there c#

Tags: c#, numbers

I'm trying to get a list with random numbers with my decision

when I start the application I get to decide which number I want it to insert/count but insert doesn't do anything, I know that am missing something coding with the number generator but I just can't find out what it is.

So basically i want it to show this if i typed 5

Random Number

Random Number

Random Number

Random Number

Random Number

then if i typed 3 i want it to show me how many three's are there.

for now I made this code:

```
Console.Write("insert number to decide: ");
int numbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Number to count: ");
int yoy = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Random random = new Random();

numbers = random.Next(0, 10);


var number = numbers;

var count = 0;
var digit = yoy;

var n = number;
while (n > 0)
{
    if (n % 10 == digit)
        count++;
    n = n / 10;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Number: {number}");
Console.WriteLine(
    $"Digit {digit} appears {count} times.");

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Why are you getting `numbers` from user (in a fragile way) if you overwrite it with a random number, right after that? Why are you reassigning the value 2 times, so that `numbers` isn't actually used for anything useful?

Comment: Your problem description & code makes little sense. Do you want to generate N single digit numbers and count how many matches a specific digit? Or generate a number of N digits and count how many digits in that number matches the specified digit?

Comment: generate a number of N digits and count how many digits in that number matches the specified digit

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to explain your code

```
Console.Write("insert number to decide: ");
int numbers = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Number to count: ");
int yoy = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

Random random = new Random();

numbers = random.Next(0, 10); // You are overwriting user input here from line 2.


var number = numbers; // Redundant duplicate variable.

var count = 0;
var digit = yoy;

var n = number;
while (n > 0)
{
    if (n % 10 == digit)
        count++;
    n = n / 10;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Number: {number}");
Console.WriteLine(
    $"Digit {digit} appears {count} times.");

Console.ReadKey();
```

What are you trying to achieve?
If you want to count the occurrence of a digit in a random number between 0 and the users input, then I would write this on line 6:

```
numbers = random.Next(0, numbers + 1);
```

Remove '+ 1' if users input should not be included.

UPDATE:

for your updated explanation i would write:

```
Console.Write("insert number to decide: ");
string userNumber = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Number to count: ");
string userYoy = Console.ReadLine();

int number = 0;
int yoy = 0;
int count = 0;

bool numbersSuccess = int.TryParse(userNumber, out number);
bool yoySuccess = int.TryParse(userYoy, out yoy);

if(numberSuccess && yoySuccess)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
   
    for(int i = 0; 0 < number; i++)
    {
        int randomNumber = random.Next(0,10);
        if(randomNumber == yoy)
        {
            count++;
        }
        Console.WriteLine($"Number: {randomNumber}");

    }
    Console.WriteLine(
    $"Digit {yoy} appears {count} times.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong, only type hole numbers!");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

UPDATE #2

For an N digit long random number, you could write something like this:

```
Console.Write("insert number to decide: ");
string userNumber = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Number to count: ");
string userYoy = Console.ReadLine();

int numberOfDigits = 0;
int yoy = 0;
int count = 0;

bool numbersSuccess = int.TryParse(userNumber, out numberOfDigits );
bool yoySuccess = int.TryParse(userYoy, out yoy);

if(numberSuccess && yoySuccess)
{
    int randomMax = (int)Math.Pow(10,numberOfDigits);

    Random random = new Random();
    int number = random.Next(0,randomMax);

    var n = number;
    while (n > 0)
    {
        if (n % 10 == digit)
            count++;
        n = n / 10;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Number: {number}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Digit {digit} appears {count} times.");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong, only type hole numbers!");
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: ... and never trust user input. Forget that `Convert` even exists. Use `int.TryParse`.

Comment: @Fildor You are absolutely correct.
1st rule of programming: Users are like small children and will try to break your code whenever and however it's possible.